# Upgrading build server to Visual Studio 2013 has broken deployment process

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2013, msdeploy

My build manager has been banging it's head on this for quite sometime.

We were using Visual Studio 2012 Professional with MSDeploy.  Everything ran fine, we were able to do builds, Xml transforms, database deployments, web deployments, etc. to various environments.

We recently upgraded our build server to Visual Studio 2013 Professional and pretty much all hell has broken loose.

We get the following errors during our build process since upgrading:

Error Code: ERROR_EXCEPTION_WHILE_CREATING_OBJECT

More Information: Object of type 'manifest' and path 'C:\Builds\90\Code\Staging - Project\Binaries\Website Deployment\Project.Web.manifest' cannot be created.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_EXCEPTION_WHILE_CREATING_OBJECT.

Error: One or more entries in the manifest 'sitemanifest' are not valid.

Error Code: FileOrFolderNotFound

More Information: Could not find file 'C:\Builds\90\Code\Staging - Project\Binaries\Website Deployment\Project.Web'.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#FileOrFolderNotFound.

Error count: 1.

We have done everything possible to fix this issue.  We have tried everything to get this building again.  Even updating the project .prj file itself to point back to older .targets v10.0 from v12.0.

When we do "change" targets, it give us this new error:

C:\Builds\90\Code\Staging - Project\Sources\Project.Web\Project.Web.csproj (3290): The "TransformXml" task was not found. Check the following: 1.) The name of the task in the project file is the same as the name of the task class. 2.) The task class is "public" and implements the Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask interface. 3.) The task is correctly declared with  in the project file, or in the *.tasks files located in the "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319" directory.

So it seems Visual Studio 2013 has modified something pretty significant in our environment to cause these errors during our Deployment process (the verbose log indicates that everything is building, just not deploying correctly).

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: Do you do any extensions to the web publishing pipeline? Perhaps to create empty folders on your web server that must exist, despite having no contents for msdeploy to sync there? I'm troubleshooting an issue along these lines myself and found this post. Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: No. We never did. We reverted back to 2012.  We have done some research since and found that the deployment process is handled way differently in 2013 than in 2012, thus causing the issues with our build scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I also recently upgraded to Visual Studio 2013 and found problems with deployment of a database project where the "Deploy" option didn't do anything and the publish didn't produce the differencing script I was expecting.

I installed the [SQl Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for VS 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42313) and it resolved the problem for me.  Perhaps it may help in your situation.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll check it out.  For now, I had to revert back to VS2012 for our build server.